# same comments on a whole column on excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've a cell with some comments on excel sheet. And i'm sure that column's(containing that cell) other cells should have same comments. So A single column all the cells should have same comments. Is there any way of doing that? Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cell with the comment in, and copy it. Then select the range of cells that you want to apply the comment to and click Paste Special -> Comments.